# Metrics not available for Azure Relay

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-relay

We are currently using Azure WCF Relays, with many listeners and senders.
But metrics are not available.

[image].

**Is there a way to activate metrics in Azure Relay?**

Comment: Is there any one got solution for this? we are also having same issue

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Comment: No, we still have this issue. We just added metrics on the web apps using Azure Relay.

Comment: Looks like it's still an issue in 2022.